# Intercepting signals from vintage computer (common ground)

Tags: microcontroller, usb, ground, ground-loop, vintage

I am trying to reverse engineer the signalling for a peripheral to an old 4-bit computer and eventually I want to emulate the peripheral and send the appropriate signals back to the computer.  I know that the logic levels are 5V TTL compliant and that the signalling is very slow (think less than 100Hz).  I plan to connect a small microcontroller (like an attiny) on the peripheral bus to sniff the signals and then to communicate those signals via an UART->USB FTDI chip that will then connect to my (modern) computer.

I just want to double check my understanding about tying the grounds together to allow the communication to take place.  The 4-bit machine has its own power supply, which will be powering the peripheral bus.  My modern computer obviously has its power supply which via USB will be powering the FTDI chip and microcontroller.  Am I correct in understanding that all I have to do is connect the ground from the 4bit computer and the USB of my computer at the USB interface and that this should be fine (that with the shared ground then the microcontroller will be able to properly read the voltages off the peripheral bus).

I have heard of ground loops happening and I am just wondering what my risk would be here (I don't think it is an issue in this case but I kind of want to ask)

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like it should be fine. Just out of curiosity, what is the 4-bit computer?

Comment: @DaveTweed Intel 4004, Intel 4040, TI TMS 1000, Nova 1200, AM 2901 bitslice, and technically perhaps the 74181. Plus, the "Nibbler" on the web now made from 7400 parts. Of course, that still leaves the question for the OP, I suppose. Those are only some possibilities.

Comment: @jonk "modern" 4-bit MCUs are really enigmatic to me: There's [MCUs](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/doc/products/mpumcu/001/rej03b0148_4508ds.pdf) with 10-bit instructions, 256 words (==4bit) of RAM, three 4-bit registers (you can combine two to make an 8 bit register), and a single 8 bit register, that's it, but a quad-channel 10 bit ADC. It really boggles my mind why you'd want to use that – and more so, why that would hit the market in 2005.

Comment: @DaveTweed, thanks for the info.  It is a NEC PD546C, it runs a knitting machine from the 1980s.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting. I hadn't heard of that one before.

Comment: Use an ohm meter on the *unpowered* system to find out if the signal ground ties back to the mains ground, typically it does.   It's if there's a substantial difference there that you could hit a problem.   Also consider using a USB based logic analyzer like a cheap CY7C68013A board with Sigrok rather than sinking time into creating your own.

Comment: @Chris Stratton.  The plug is a two prong unpolarized connection to the mains.  No earth ground.  I measure infinite resistance (my meter goes to 20M ohm from the digital ground to each prong on the power cable